# Better solution to implement an AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, filter, autocomplete

I'm working to implement a solution to search among 10000 products and retrieve information about them. So I decided to implement an AutoCompleteTextView to help the user find the product. Searching among different solutions I implemented one option and it works fine but I wonder if are there some guidelines to know if a solutions can be improve or its optimal?

The general structure of my solutions is the following:

---- My data class ----

```
public class CountryItem {

private String countryName;
private int flagImage;

public CountryItem(){}

public CountryItem(String countryName, int flagImage) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
    this.flagImage = flagImage;
}

public ArrayList<CountryItem> fillCountryList() {
    ArrayList<CountryItem> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
    countryList.add(new CountryItem("Afghanistan", R.drawable.afghanistan));
    countryList.add(new CountryItem("Albania", R.drawable.albania));
    countryList.add(new CountryItem("Algeria", R.drawable.algeria));
    return countryList;
}

public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}

public int getFlagImage() {
    return flagImage;
}
}
```

---- MainClass ----

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<CountryItem> countryList = new CountryItem().fillCountryList();
    AutoCompleteTextView editText = findViewById(R.id.actv);
    AutoCompleteCountryAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteCountryAdapter(this, countryList);
    editText.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

AdapterClass

```
public class AutoCompleteCountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryItem> {

private List<CountryItem> countryListFull;

public AutoCompleteCountryAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<CountryItem> countryList) {
    super(context, 0, countryList);
    countryListFull = new ArrayList<>(countryList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return countryFilter;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.country_autocomplete_row, parent, false
        );
    }

    TextView textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
    ImageView imageViewFlag = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_flag);

    CountryItem countryItem = getItem(position);

    if (countryItem != null) {
        textViewName.setText(countryItem.getCountryName());
        imageViewFlag.setImageResource(countryItem.getFlagImage());
    }

    return convertView;
}

private Filter countryFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        List<CountryItem> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            suggestions.addAll(countryListFull);
        } else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (CountryItem item : countryListFull) {
                if (item.getCountryName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    suggestions.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        results.values = suggestions;
        results.count = suggestions.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        clear();
        addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        return ((CountryItem) resultValue).getCountryName();
    }
};
}
```

Some links or comments could help me a lot to know if the solution can be improve in any aspect.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely a lot of ways you can improve the solution.
 1. Debounce factor to reduce UI redrawing.

The code examples and other alternatives depends on your current architecture and dependencies. In case you have plans to RxJava can refer this

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=auto+complete+with+rx+java&oq=auto+complete+with+rx+java&aqs=chrome..69i57.6944j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks, I know the question is very subjective but in this case I would really know if there are better options or tools to implement a solution. I'm  sure your commet will help me to improve.